# Using Arduino UNO for uploading a sketch to the Espresso Lite v2

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, esp8266, arduino-ide, ftdi

I am trying to use my Arduino UNO as a programming interface to load sketches on the Espresso Lite v2.

I followed the instructions to setup the Wifi network (long press gpio13 and the AP thing), but now I want to run code on it.

I uploaded this sketch to the UNO, [in order to allow for serial communication](https://oscarliang.com/use-arduino-as-usb-serial-adapter-converter/)(i chose method 3):

`void setup(){
  pinMode(0,INPUT);
  pinMode(1,INPUT);
}
void loop(){
}`

Afterwards I configured the Arduino IDE with the necessary libraries and device manager plugins for the Espresso, so I selected "Espresso Lite 2.0" as the target board and for programmer "Arduino as ISP".

This is what my tools menu looks like:

[image: tools menu screenshot]

I connected the 3.3V, GND, TX (to TX) and RX (to RX) and RESET (to RST) headers from the Arduino UNO to the Espresso Lite holes. If I open the Serial Monitor I can see serial output so I think the connections are correct.

I tried to upload an empty sketch and i got these errors (verbose upload):

`Sketch uses 246096 bytes (23%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1044464 bytes.
Global variables use 27588 bytes (33%) of dynamic memory, leaving 54332 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 81920 bytes.
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\esptool\0.4.13/esptool.exe -vv -cd ck -cb 115200 -cp COM3 -ca 0x0 -cz 0x400000 -ca 0x00000 -cf C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_89/sketch_oct08a.ino.bin 
esptool v0.4.13 - (c) 2014 Ch. Klippel <ck@atelier-klippel.de>
    setting board to ck
    setting baudrate from 115200 to 115200
    setting port from COM1 to COM3
    setting address from 0x00000000 to 0x00000000
    setting erase size to 0x00400000
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
opening bootloader
resetting board
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    read 0, requested 1
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    serialport_receive_C0: 0D instead of C0
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    serialport_receive_C0: 45 instead of C0
resetting board
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    read 0, requested 1
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    serialport_receive_C0: 0D instead of C0
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    serialport_receive_C0: 74 instead of C0
resetting board
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    read 0, requested 1
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    serialport_receive_C0: 0D instead of C0
trying to connect
    flush start
    setting serial port timeouts to 1 ms
    setting serial port timeouts to 1000 ms
    flush complete
    espcomm_send_command: sending command header
    espcomm_send_command: sending command payload
    serialport_receive_C0: 45 instead of C0
warning: espcomm_sync failed
error: espcomm_open failed`

This is the serial output after i tried to upload:

[image: serial monitor window]

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: @gre_gor this is different: I am trying to troubleshoot the "sketch upload" function on a specific board

Comment: You can't use "Arduino as ISP" to program an ESP8266.

Comment: @gre_gor What should I select in this case? Is the fact that I can see serial output irrelevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't connect reset pins together.  Selecting "Arduino as ISP" is irrelevant in many ways.

Put the esp8266 into flashing mode by resetting it with io 0 LOW at reboot (hold button GPIO0 and click the RESET button). **And then Upload from IDE**. The esptool can't reset the board to flashing mode because you don't have RTS and DTS line from Uno.

Picture from manufacturers page:

[image]

Comment: This solved my issue!